# EJBConfigurationException: Bean class for EJB not found

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, ejb, websphere

I have an java web-project where ejb's (3.1) are configured. When I add (add projects) the ear-project to the local websphere aplication server v8.0 (in eclipse) and start the server I receive the following error:

Error while processing references for EJB-in-WAR: com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBConfigurationException: The bean class "nl.xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.GebruikerFacade" for EJB "xx-xx-ear#xx-xx-web.war#GebruikerFacade" is not found.

Because I couldn't find the problem I deployed the ear-file to the websphere application server via the admin console (new application). The ear-file I created using mvn clean install package.
Then when starting the application from within de admin console the error is not given.
In stead it is reporting that the remote interface of the GebruikerFacade is binded.

What can be the cause of the error when starting the application server where the ear-project is added using add project.

Extra info: Added 20141211
The reason why the bean class cannot be found is the fact that when the ear is deployed to the webspere application server via add project the business interface is empty within the deployed ear.
This is a property in Enterprise Java Bean properties/Bind EJB Business of an Enterprise bean.
The module, bean and uri property are set but the business interface which has to be the full path to the Remote interface class is not.
When de ear is deployed on the application server via new application the business interface contains the Remote interface Class.

Console-output in new answer below.

Comment: As always with these type of problems I would clean everything to start with. Project, deploy folder of application server etc.

Comment: Did clean project, fysical remove of target-directories but doesn't solve the problem. At the moment when starting the server I do it via clean... which cleans/starts the server.

Comment: I would also, outside of eclipse, clean the deploy directory. Clean in eclipse should work but I wouldn't trust it to 100%.

Comment: Try the following - in the Server view, open your test env server and in the `Publishing settings ...` try to uncheck `Minimize application files..` if you have it set. Restart the server, remove and add your project again.

Comment: Minimize application files doesn't solve the problem unfortunately

Comment: This is probably somehow related to maven directory structure. You can also try to switch in server configuration to `Run server with resources on server` and redeploy. And paste whole stacktrace not just piece of it.

Comment: Added two answers containing extra information. To much characters to put it in the question all together.

Answer (score 2):

The first error in the console-output when the ear-project is deployed to the server using "right click server - add/remove project":

```
 [11-12-14 8:14:39:832 CET] 00000030 ComponentData E   CWMDF0012E: The bean class nl.company.rvl.facade.GebruikerFacade for EJB 
rvl-ear#rvl-web.war#GebruikerFacade is not found.
```

Somehow the "Starting EJB jar" proces is not initiated at that point. 
If the ear-file is added as a new application within the admin console and this application is started that proces is taking place giving the
following output:

```
[11-12-14 9:01:16:381 CET] 00000047 AbstractEJBRu I   WSVR0037I: Starting EJB jar: rvl-web-2015.2.10.00-SNAPSHOT.war
[11-12-14 9:01:16:881 CET] 00000047 EJBContainerI I   CNTR0167I: The server is binding the nl.company.rvl.facade.GebruikerFacadeRemote interface of the GebruikerFacade enterprise bean in the rvl-web-2015.2.10.00-SNAPSHOT.war module of the rvl-ear application.  The binding location is: ejb/gebruikerFacade-bnd
[11-12-14 9:01:16:897 CET] 00000047 AbstractEJBRu I   CNTR0167I: The server is binding the nl.company.rvl.facade.GebruikerFacadeRemote interface of the GebruikerFacade enterprise bean in the rvl-web-2015.2.10.00-SNAPSHOT.war module of the rvl-ear application.  The binding location is: java:global/rvl-ear/rvl-web-2015.2.10.00-SNAPSHOT/GegevenspartnerFacade!nl.company.rvl.facade.GebruikerFacadeRemote
[11-12-14 9:01:16:897 CET] 00000047 EJBContainerI I   CNTR0167I: The server is binding the nl.company.rvl.facade.GebruikerFacade interface of the GebruikerFacade enterprise bean in the rvl-web-2015.2.10.00-SNAPSHOT.war module of the rvl-ear application.  The binding location is: ejblocal:ejb/gebruikerFacade-bnd
[11-12-14 9:01:16:897 CET] 00000047 AbstractEJBRu I   CNTR0167I: The server is binding the nl.company.rvl.facade.GebruikerFacade interface of the GebruikerFacade enterprise bean in the rvl-web-2015.2.10.00-SNAPSHOT.war module of the rvl-ear application.  The binding location is: java:global/rvl-ear/rvl-web-2015.2.10.00-SNAPSHOT/GebruikerFacade!nl.company.rvl.facade.GebruikerFacade
[11-12-14 9:01:16:912 CET] 00000047 AbstractEJBRu I   WSVR0057I: EJB jar started: rvl-web-2015.2.10.00-SNAPSHOT.war
```

Answer (score 0):

In the tab of Servers, make a full publish of your project. Even if you save it, you have to publish it into your server. It's a bit annoying the fact of having to publish everytime you make a small change, but is the way to deploy the .war into the server.

If that doesn't work, try to delete the server and configure a new one.

Have a nice code!

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly with a full publish. I start the server using "Clean..." which cleans, starts and publish. No result however.
Also I did try configuring a new server already but no result :(

Comment: Are you using eclipse?

Comment: I use Eclipse Kepler.

Comment: There is a tab in the eclipse that puts "Servers", if you don't see it try 'Window/Show View/Servers'. There will you see the configured servers. Expand your server, right clic and Full Publish. Then run your bean on a browser